# IQ matrix type question

Tags: pattern

what one should fill in the bottom right square?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are all of the partially filled in dots supposed to be the same? It's hard to tell with the way it was copied/printed.

Comment: and some of them are hard to tell if they count as partially filled or as black

Comment: The top row has one black, one white and one partially filled circle in each square. The second row has one white and two partially filled circles in the first square, and one black and two partially filled circles in the second. The third row has three partially filled. Of the options, a, b, e, and f each have three partially filled circles. c and d each have one black, one white and one partially filled circle.

Comment: @user38351 Maybe draw the image yourself in paint or something? Or just using a pen and paper, it's easier than explaining the images.

Comment: I've tried to create a clearer version of the problem (above) but I'll admit to having no idea what the answer is!

Comment: @user38351 maybe sharing where you took the question from would help if that's the case?

Comment: I got it from an acquaintance a few years ago. She said it was from a test she took. I've no other information on the problem, sorry.

Comment: @user38351 so if I would say: It is 2! - I can't be sure, since you don't know answer, or?

Comment: I really don't know the answer.